# How can I support different configurations of the same JSON data in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to grab a value from some JSON data. The key the value is stored under can be different. I would like to support both versions.

I have tried doing conditional statements to check to see what version the system might be running.

```
if csv_json['com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef']['path'] != None :
    csv_path = csv_json['com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef']['path']
else:
    csv_path = csv_json['path']
```

If I run the code above on a system that is compatible with the `csv_json['com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef']['path']` format then everything works. If I run it on a system supporting the `csv_json['path']` format then it fails with

```
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 38, in main
    if csv_json['path'] != None :
KeyError: 'path'
```

and of course if I flip the conditions I get the opposite results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if 'com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef' in csv_json:
```

or even better:

```
local_file_ref = csv_json.get('com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef')
if local_file_ref:
    csv_path = local_file_ref['path']
else:
    csv_path = csv_json['path']
```

The `.get()` method of `dict` will return `None` (or an optional default value you can pass as the second argument) if the key is not found.

A one liner version could be:

```
csv_path = (csv_json.get('com.revl.fileutils.LocalFileRef') or csv_json)['path']
```